# Some android apps are being auto-updated on the fly

Tags: android

OS: Android.

I noticed something weird in 2 different apps that I have installed in my phone, while I don't have auto-update feature turned on from Google play services those couple of apps are being updated on the fly, I checked this with a friend and he told me the same is happening with his version as well.

One of the examples is the *Uber* app, where every now and then you notice something new (or modified) without updating, a small e.g: **Contact driver** button...

I know those things can be built in and customised on login by fetching some initialisation parameters from the server and deciding the existing layout and/or anything else (which means they should be pre-designed), but just wanted to make sure and check in the community, is there a new way of development out there that is giving flexibility and I don't yet know about it, because I don't think they are using web views to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

Which phone do you have ?

Some of the phone generally have hidden pre installed services in device which will promote services/Application. In your case it might be the case.

Comment: I don't think this is the case, I have Samsung Note III Neo, and Core II and both of them are behaving the same way...